# Error Cast Converting SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
select campo1 as AGR_Number, campo2  as fattura, 
        campo76 as cod_periodo, campo78 as cod_scenario, 
        campo11 as origine, campo8 as Stazione,     
        campo13 as agent, campo30 as AAT_RATE, 
        sum (cast(campo30 as numeric (9,2))) AS AAT_rate 
from map_dati_trasformati 
where cod_mappatura = 'CARICA_NOL_CSV' 
AND CAMPO30 <> 0 
GROUP BY campo1, campo2, campo76, campo78, campo11 , 
        campo8, campo13, campo30
```

this conversion reply me this error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'AAT Rate' to data type int.

what is the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is in `campo30`

Comment: That error means you have a value that cannot become a number

Comment: The error is rather self-explanatory - you have non-numeric values in the `campo30` column that it can't convert.  You should take a closer look at your data.

Comment: How do you think db should convert `AAT Rate` to an int value?

Comment: A value of the field `campo30` contains the text `'AAT Rate'` which cannot be converted to an int when `CAMPO30 <> 0 ` is evaluated.

Comment: This is neither C nor C++. Provide a [mcve]. I removed the tags of the unrelated languages. And C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: aat rate have only numeric value or null

Comment: You have ALSO used `as AAT_RATE` as an alias on 2 different result columns. Could that have something to do with the error

Comment: `select count(*) from map_dati_trasformati where campo30 = 'AAT Rate'` returns what?

Comment: reply me =1 what do you recommend me?

Comment: @RubenLombi run this query -> select * from map_dati_trasformati where campo30 = 'AAT Rate' ... and check the campo30 column...you must update its value to something that can be converted to numeric

Comment: If its 1 then there is a string in that column so you need to remove it (and probably make the column a nullable int as currently its a varchar) or exclude it from the query with a `!= 'AAT Rate'` or numeric filter ...

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that pops to the eye is the upper case AS and the same column alias (by default mysql is not case sensitive).
Can you try it like this ?

```
select campo1 as AGR_Number, campo2  as fattura, 
    campo76 as cod_periodo, campo78 as cod_scenario, 
    campo11 as origine, campo8 as Stazione,     
    campo13 as agent, campo30 as AAT_RATE, 
    sum (cast(campo30 as numeric (9,2))) as AAT_rate_sum 
from map_dati_trasformati 
where cod_mappatura = 'CARICA_NOL_CSV' 
AND CAMPO30 <> 0 
GROUP BY campo1, campo2, campo76, campo78, campo11 , 
        campo8, campo13, campo30
```

Comment: The error is `AAT Rate` with no `_` so is unrelated and dup aliases are fine

Comment: ah, good catch @AlexK. , no '_' in the error so it look like you have the literal value of 'AAT rate' inside the campo30 column.

Comment: what do you get running this : select count(*) from map_dati_trasformati where campo30 = 'AAT rate'