# I need to convert a Postgres specific query to SQL Server (T-SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

I have a query running on postgres, and I need to convert it, due it should work on MS-SQL Server.

```
case when position('.' in campo30) >= 1
     then CAST(replace(replace(CAMPO30,'.',''),',','.') AS FLOAT)
     else CAST(replace(CAMPO30,',','.') AS FLOAT)
end
```

What would be the equivalent code for MS-SQL Server?

Comment: The header says "to SQL", which implies ANSI SQL, but then you tag MySQL. Which one do you want?

Comment: agree with jarlh. But I'd not say, sql implies ansi sql, more, postgresql is an sql-dialect, too. So OP needs to specify to what dialect he wants to convert (or to ansi sql). + OP should post what he tried so far. I think this is just a "someone do this for me, I' don't want to"

Comment: At a guess, they mean [tag:ms-sql] but think "SQL" means "microsoft SQL server", and the [tag:mysql] tag is just tag-spam from misunderstanding difference between MySQL and PostgreSQL. Their other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/42417364/398670 refers to "conversion failed" which is a SQL Server error.

Comment: @Ruben, please provide *complete* and *clear* questions. Also explain what you already tried. This isn't a code writing service, it's to help you if you get stuck not do it all for you.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, I think my question is related to correct sintax for converting expression because don't works in microsoft sql server management studio :( postiion for example is not recognize

Comment: Postgres **is** using SQL, so "convert to SQL" doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On SQL-Server use [CHARINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)

**CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind , expressionToSearch [ , start_location ] )**

```
DECLARE @CAMPO30 varchar(64) = '2,663.25';

SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.', @CAMPO30) > 1
            THEN CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(@CAMPO30,'.',''),',','.') AS FLOAT)
            ELSE CAST(REPLACE(@CAMPO30,',','.') AS FLOAT)
       END AS CAMPO30
GO

| CAMPO30 |
| ------: |
| 2.66325 |
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d1d8f8aa17eb31b669ae97ab84a4ec37)*

Comment: Thanks Now Everythings Works :)